# Find Google OAuth2 clientId and Secret

Tags: google-signin

I'd like to use Google as a 3rd party sign-on provider for my app running on localhost. This isn't my first rodeo, and I would have thought that this would be straight forward.

However I'm struggling to find the place within the google system where I can create my app and manage my client_id, secret, callback url and other properties, specifically just to use google as a 3rd party sign-in provider.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to create a project in [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com). There are tons of APIs available for you to use here. But for the 3rd party sign-in provider (social login) you have to enable `Google+ API` which would provide details such as profile, email, etc. This can be done by accessing the APIs and Services menu.

[image]

Once you have done this, you can proceed to the Credentials menu and create a new set of credentials. Once you register your application here, you will be provided with `client_id` and `client_secret` and other options related to OAuth and OpenID.